# How to display some list from controller when dropdown option is selected in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display data in the view from controller, when selecting a dropdown option.
I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I dont know how to create list in controller and display it.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: [Using the DropDownList Helper with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc)

Comment: Or are you clear about how to handle the dropdown and just want to know how to create the list? Please elaborate your question and show the code you already have in place.

Comment: I am able to display the selected item in the list. but I want to display 4 or 5 items when an option is selected..these item should come from controller not from database.also I dont know how to add 4 or 5 items in the list in the controller...

Comment: Now I am clear with my question and I have done this.

Answer (score 0):

Example ViewModel for single item to be displayed:

```
public class ItemViewModel {
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Controller generates a list of items to display:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ShowListForOption(int selectedOptionValue) {

    // ViewModel for overall page is a list of items to display
    var viewModel = new List<ItemViewModel>();

    // create and add multiple items depending on selected option
    if (selectedOptionValue == 1) {
        viewModel.Add(new ItemViewModel { Name = "A" });
        viewModel.Add(new ItemViewModel { Name = "B" });
    }
    else  if (selectedOptionValue == 2) { /* add other items */ }

    return View("ShowList", viewModel);
}
```

The view "ShowList" renders the items using a `for` loop (a `for` loop will also work if you want to send a list of items back to the controller):

```
@model IEnumerable<ItemViewModel>
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Name)
}
```

Comment: Thanx Georg. Now I want to interact with database and I want to display data from database when dropdown button is clicked.

Comment: Please create a new question, because this scenario has to be handled differently. You will have to use AJAX to achieve this.